# К какому орфографическому принципу относится выбор О/Ё после шипящих (под ударением)?

Tags: орфография

**Орфографические принципы**  русского языка  можно было бы изложить **просто и понятно даже ребенку младшего школьного возраста.**

Но в тех редакциях, которые обычно предлагаются, **тема из простой превращается в сложную, противоречивую и совершенно бесполезную**, как мне кажется, с практической точки зрения. **Она ведет не к ясности и пониманию языка, а совершенно в обратную сторону.**

Например:https://studfiles.net/preview/6313221/

Не знаю, насколько авторитетен источник, но там про выбор О/Ё написано следующее.

**Морфологический принцип**: употребление буквы ё после шипящих в ударной позиции в корнях слов, а также в суффиксах глаголов и отглагольных слов (***ночёвка – ночевать, шёпот – шептать, размежёвка – размежевать***);

**Фонетический принцип:** написание буквы о в суффиксах –онок –онка после шипящих (***медвежонок, шапчонка*** и т. п.);

И еще (для справок): В современном русском языке существует **три принципа орфографии**: морфологический (**фонемный, фонематический, морфофонематический, фонемно-морфологический**), фонетический и исторический (этимологический, или традиционный).

**Какой из четырех вариантов морфологического принципа здесь упомянут и что это такое вообще?**

**И о фонетическом принципе:** медвежонок, шапчонка. После твердого Ж пишется О, а после мягкого Ч тоже О. (Обычно дети очень любят после Ч писать Ё). В чем здесь проявляется фонетический принцип?

Правда, есть объяснение: **Фонетический принцип** (или фонетические написания) заключается в том, что написание передает звучание слова, буквой в данном случае обозначается не фонема, а звук. Фонетические написания **близки** к фонетический транскрипции (как известно, транскрипция – это передача звучащей речи на письме).

Очень длинное высказывание, а **можно ли сказать короче: "как слышится, так и пишется, выбор буквы делается по слуху"?** И насколько фонетические написания **близки** к транскрипции, есть ли разница?

После таких определений иногда думается, что нет тут глубокого смысла, но есть люди, которые сами не понимают, что они пишут.

Answer (score 1):

```
   думается, что нет тут глубокого смысла, но есть люди, которые сами
   не понимают, что они пишут.
```

Уважаемая Jasmin, едва появится фраза, обращённая к Вам, типа "Вы не поняли", "Вы не разобрались", как Вы обвиняете собеседника в неуважении и неэтичности,а сами позволяете себе такие фразы в адрес разработчиков учебника для студентов.Это этично?

Всё у них верно, просто при обращении к младшим школьникам говорят "как слышим, так и пишем", а для студентов  чуть научнее: "написание передает звучание слова", "пишем в соответствии с произношением". Студент должен различать звук и фонему, школьнику это не обязательно. Тема "Принципы русской орфографии"вообще появляется только в 10 классе, и это правильно, не стоит "замудрять" мозги младшим школьникам.

```
    о фонетическом принципе: медвежонок, шапчонка. После твердого Ж 
    пишется О, а после мягкого Ч тоже О. (Обычно дети очень любят 
    после Ч писать Ё). В чем здесь проявляется фонетический принцип?
```

А какой же ещё? Именно фонетический. Слышится везде О, а не Ё=ЙО.

А что пишется после твёрдого-мягкого согласного - это уже **не орфография**, а  **графика** - её слоговой принцип.Главнейшее отступление от слогового принципа - обозначение гласных звуков после согласных, непарных по твердости-мягкости. Так, после всегда твердых согласных [ж], [ш], [ц] гласные звуки обозначаются, вопреки слоговому принципу, буквами и, е, ё, изредка ю, я (ср. жир, ширь, жест, шест, жёлоб, шёпот, брошюра, жюри, парашют, цифра, цепь, Коцюбинский, Цявловский и т.п.); после всегда мягких [ч], [щ], вопреки слоговому принципу, пишутся буквы а, о, у (ср. чаша, чокнуться, чудо, пища, Щорс, щука и т.п.). Эти отступления от слогового принципа в современной русской графике сложились исторически. В современном русском языке звуки [ж], [ш], [ц] не имеют мягких разновидностей, а звуки [ч], [щ] - твердых разновидностей. Поэтому твердость и мягкость этих звуков обозначается самими согласными буквами, которые являются однозначными и не требуют обозначения последующими гласными буквами.

Ночёвка – ночевать, шёпот – шептать, размежёвка – размежевать - морфологический принцип: морфемы под ударением и без ударения пишутся одинаково. По традиции этот принцип называют морфологическим, хотя правильнее было бы назвать его морфофонематическим, так как, во-первых, одни и те же буквы алфавита обозначают фонему во всех ее видоизменениях, во-вторых, этот принцип обеспечивает одинаковое написание морфем. Но это снова для студентов, а не для школьников. Отсюда и разновидности - фонемный, фонематический, морфофонематический, фонемно-морфологический, что является ведущим, такое и название, школьникам это тоже не нужно, а студенты пусть разбираются, им полезно. Как и транскрипция фонематическая, им бы фонетическую понять.

В написаниях О/Ё после шипящих есть и дифференцирующий принцип:

написание букв о или ё для разграничения имен существительных и глагольных словоформ (ожог, поджог – имена существительные и ожёг, поджёг – глаголы в форме прошедшего времени мужского рода).

Так что орфограмма О/Ё после шипящих использует все 3 основных принципа русской орфографии.

Comment: Знаю я всё про студентов и фонемы, приходилось на эту тему курсовую писать. Что-нибудь там изменилось с тех пор? Сейчас посмотрим. "Между представителями двух фонологических школ существуют разногласия..." Ну конечно,  несущественные такие разногласия, просто в слове "вода" у одной школы фонема О, а у другой фонема А.  И вот этими школами студентам можно замудрять мозги, а для школьников и орфографических принципов будет достаточно.  Грамоте научить не получается,  так хотя бы какую-то учебную деятельность надо проявить.

Comment: Наверное, неэтично так думать, но всё это, по-моему,  напоминает псевдонауку ( деятельность или учение, представляемые сторонниками как научные, но по сути таковыми не являющиеся). Как можно уважать людей, которые  не в состоянии разобраться и донести до учащихся принципиально важный принцип: наше письмо имеет ФОНЕМАТИЧЕСКУЮ, а не фонетическую природу.   Да только слово "ФОНЕМА"  в школе под запретом,  а вместо этого детям  дают какую-то искусственную мешанину из звуков и букв, чтобы хоть как-то  объяснить, почему мы пишем не так, как говорим.

Comment: Вторую часть Вашего ответа мне, наверное, изучать придется, пока ничего не поняла. "Слышится везде О, а не Ё=ЙО", это и есть фонетический принцип? Я считала, что фонетические написания только в слабых позициях, и потом после согласных йотированные гласные мягкость обозначают, при чем тут «слышится О, а не ЙО».

Comment: "В чем здесь проявляется фонетический принцип?"- Как раз в том, что после Ж слышится О и после Ч - О,а Вы считаете, что после Ч можно услышать Ё? Или что здесь морфологический принцип - суфф. ОНК всегда пишется с О? А как же зубрёнок, оленёнок? Или это традиционное написание? Но это же не исключение из правила "как слышим, так и пишем"? Всё по правилу.

Comment: Фонетическое написание в русском языке не только в слабых позициях, но и в сильных, другое дело, что гласный под ударением не всегда является орфограммой, стул, например, но вот О/Ё после шипящих - орфограмма, хотя и под ударением, но в корне мы проверяем её единообразием написания в однокоренных словах по морфологическому признаку, а в суффиксах как слышим, так и пишем в отымённых словах после шипящих(по фонетическому), а в отглагольных  - Ё (дифференцирующее написание, т.к. в суфф. глаголов  О не бывает)

Comment: Фонетические написания можно найти где угодно, для этого надо сделать очень простую вещь: дать им ДРУГОЕ определение, отличное от общепринятого. В действительности же всё, что надо нашим уважаемым разработчикам учебных пособий, так это выделить в отдельную группу графические орфограммы, дополняющие правила письма. Тогда всё будет просто и ясно, а этот МИКС, который к тому же изучается в школе, для нормальных людей абсолютно неприемлем. Хоть это и неэтичное мнение по отношению к разработчикам, но оно очень похоже на истину.